# Normal force between two boards

Tags: statics, friction

This is a problem from the book Engineering Mechanics Statics vol-1 by Meriam Kraige

The rectangular steel yoke is used to prevent slippage between the two boards under tensile loads $P$ .If the coefficients of static friction between the yoke and the board surfaces and between the boards are all $0.30$ the question is to determine the maximum value of $h$ for which there is no slipping and to find out the corresponding normal force $N$ between the two boards for $P=800N$ if impending motion occurs at all surfaces.
[image]

Here is what I tried

For the first part if $\theta$ denotes the angle between the top part of yoke and horizontal then $\cos \theta = \frac{200}{210}=\frac{150}{h}$ which gives $h=157.5 mm$

For the second part I tried to draw the FBD of the top block.

[image]

From FBD $$P=f_1+f_2+f_3+f_4$$ and $$mg=N_3-N_1$$ Also by taking moments about COM I got $P=f_3-f_1$.However I am not able to proceed after this.Any help shall be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: To my understanding, the second part is quite direct: you have the force P, the coefficient and you need the normal force N. For the first part, I have not a clear idea, but your numbers seem not correct: you use the horizontal values which have no impact and don't use the important value  of the coefficient.

Comment: @AdrianMarie I couldn't get your last line.can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: You don't need the $N_2$ and $N_3$ because the yoke is wider than the board, therefore, it can be assumed that there is no contact between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer it.

First, draw the forces acting upon it. (I considered only the top plank/board as it is symmetric with the bottom board). Refer to the figure below.

[image: Reference drawing]

Separating the upper plank and analyzing the forces upon it, you will get the figure below.

[image: Figure 2]

Note that $F_{\text f1}=P_y (0.3)$ and $F_{\text f2}=N(0.3)$, therefore:

Summing up forces in the x-axis gives:

$$0.3(P_y)+0.3(N)=800$$

and Summing up forces in the y-axis gives:

$$N-P_y=0$$

Solving both,

$$P_y=N=1,333.33\ N$$

Solving also for $F_{\text f1}$ gives $F_{\text f1}=400\ N.$

Solving for the angle of inclination of the yoke gives

$$\theta = arctan (400/1333.33)=16.70\ degrees$$

therefore, $h = 150/\cos(16.70)=156.60\ mm$

Comment: There is a shortcut to this. :)